# Do you need a separate IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider for each custom attribute?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

The code seems straightforward for an adapter provider, something like this:

```
public class KittensMustBeCuteAttributeAdapterProvider : IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider
{
    private readonly IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider _baseProvider = new ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider();

    public IAttributeAdapter GetAttributeAdapter(ValidationAttribute attribute, IStringLocalizer stringLocalizer)
    {
        if (attribute is KittensMustBeCuteAttribute)
        {

            return new KittensMustBeCuteAttributeAdapter(attribute as KittensMustBeCuteAttribute, stringLocalizer);
        }
        else
        {
            return _baseProvider.GetAttributeAdapter(attribute, stringLocalizer);
        }
    }
}
```

Looks to me like I could rename this adapter provider to be generic and use it for all of my custom attributes, as I have several (not just `KittensMustBeCuteAttribute`).

However I can't find anything indicating on whether or not this is OK or if you need one each. All of the examples I've seen have it named like I have, specific to the attribute.

Can I just re-use one AdapterProvider by expanding my `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I should have just kept going, it became apparent afterwards that the adapter provider is registered as a singleton to be resolved through DI, therefore you have to have a single one containing all your custom attributes.